# Multi-dimensional array in strong_params

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to accept a multi-dimensional array using strong_params.

I was using:

```
params.require(:name).permit(array_param: [])
```

and it was working fine for regular arrays.

Now I got a multi-dimensional array format I have to deal with. The previous solution is not working for the following case.

```
[[1],[2],[2,1]]
```

I would gladly appreciate some guidance.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the long route and do it like this

```
def permitted_params
  permitted = params.require(:name)

  if params[:name][:array_param].present?
    permitted[:name][:array_param] = params[:name].require(:array_param)
  end

  permitted
end
```

Comment: not sure if this would work, as :array_param is nested inside :name

Comment: this worked permitted[:name][:array_param] = params[:name].require(:array_param)

Comment: Thank you, worked great! In the if statement I did check for params[:name][:array_param].present?